# How to load default view in Prism WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am using this Repo:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation

It works, but I need to make changes:
when run the app, I must click to the selected view to load, so I need to show the default view.
[image]

After click

[image]

the `Bootstrapper.cs` file code:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Unity;
using NavigationParticipation.Views;
using System.Windows;
using Prism.Modularity;
using ModuleA;

namespace NavigationParticipation
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            var catalog = (ModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog;
            catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleAModule));
        }
    }
}
```

Folder Structure (Solution)

[image]

And how to show The Login window Or another window before initialize the MainWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is to add CompositeCommand somewhere outside modules so they all can use it...

```
public class ApplicationCommands
{
    public static CompositeCommand NavigateCommand = new CompositeCommand();
}
```

and then if you wanna ViewA to be default

inside ModuleAModule in method Initialize() add

```
ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand.Execute(typeof(ViewA));
```

if you want ViewB to be default then inside ModuleBModule in method Initialize() add

```
ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand.Execute(typeof(ViewB));
```

There are couple more ways, but dont know your logic and all code used, so this one seems the easiest one.

and if you are using `IRegionManager` then you can do something like this.

```
 _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("YourRegionName", typeof(ViewA));
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve A part of the Problem :

by adding this code to :

```
17-BasicRegionNavigation/ModuleA/ModuleAModule.cs
```

this code:

```
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri("ViewA", UriKind.Relative));
```

where: `ViewA` correspond to the Target view that you want to show.
and the `ContentRegion`  correspond to your MainRegion, you can find it in :

```
17-BasicRegionNavigation/BasicRegionNavigation/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs
```

and looks like:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using ModuleA.Views;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Regions;
using Prism.Unity;
using System;

namespace ModuleA
{
    public class ModuleAModule : IModule
    {
        IRegionManager _regionManager;
        IUnityContainer _container;

        public ModuleAModule(RegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;
            _container = container;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>();
            _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewB>();
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri("ViewA", UriKind.Relative));

        }
    }
}
```

**Now How To Add Login Window before MainWindow initialized ??**

Comment: For that you can in startup (bootstrapper) you can set your login to be called 1rst and only if login passes then you can mainWindow from login window